# Alias a class with a different type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, class, export

I am trying to re-export an externally defined class with an internally declared class type in Typescript. I would like the re-exported class to work both as a class (with `new`) and as a type. I have tried code like the following:

```js
class XReal { foo() {return 5} }
declare class XFake { bar(): number }
export const XExport = (XReal as any) as typeof XFake

declare const c: XExport;
const ci = new XExport;
```

I can use `new XExport`, but I cannot use `XExport` as a type.

Is there a way to re-alias `XReal` as `XExport` but have type `XFake` while being able to use `XExport` as both a type and as a class constructor?

Comment: ① Please [edit] the question to use just your bottom code block; the type `XFake` is an instance type and you've already solved that problem by using `typeof XFake`, so it's at best a distraction.  ② `class` declarations declare both a named value and a named type, but `const` declarations only declare a value.  If you want both you need to declare both [as shown here](https://tsplay.dev/N738RN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I didn't know you could declare a type with the same name as a variable! Yes, that fixes my issue :-)

Comment: Okay I'll write up my answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TypeScript, types and values have separate namespaces.  You can have a type named `Foo` and an unrelated value named `Foo` and the compiler will not confuse them, because they are separate kinds of thing and appear in different contexts:

```
const Foo = "abc"; // <-- value named Foo
interface Foo { x: number; } // <-- type named Foo

const x = Foo; // <-- this is the value
// const x: "abc";

const y: Foo = { x: 123 }; // <-- this is the type

type Z = typeof Foo; // <-- this is the value, but Z is a type
// type Z = "abc"
```

This might be confusing to a human being whose native language is something other than TypeScript, but the compiler understands from context when a name refers to a type versus a value.  Just like an American native speaker of English probably has no trouble understanding the sentences "My cousin Virginia lives in Georgia" and "My cousin Georgia lives in Virginia", as context lets you know whether a name refers to a person or a place.

There is no *necessary* relationship between a type and a value that share a name.

---

Now, declarations like `interface` and `type` declare a named type while variable declarations like `let` and `const` declare a named value.  And [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) declarations are special because they declare *both a type and a value* of the same name.  The type corresponds to an instance of the class, while the value is the class constructor itself:

```
class Bar { a = 1; }

const b: Bar = new Bar();
// ----> ^^^       ^^^ <---
// instance type        constructor value

const baz = Bar; // <-- constructor value
// const baz: typeof Bar
```

So while there is no *necessary* relationship between types and values of the same name, ones that arise from `class` declarations will have the relationship that the named value is a constructor of the named type.  (People are often confused into thinking that this common relationship is necessary, and then try to write `typeof X` to refer to a possibly nonexistent constructor for `X` instances.  Hopefully you won't make this mistake after this explanation.)

---

Anyway, if you want to replicate the effects of a `class` declaration without actually using one, so that people can pretend that it was declared that way, you'll need to make an appropriate named type (via `interface` or `type`) and an appropriate named value (via `let` or `const`).  In your case, it would be like this:

```
declare class XFake { bar(): number }
export type XExport = XFake; // named type    
export const XExport = (XReal as any) as typeof XFake // named value
```

Note that you don't necessarily even need your `XFake` declaration, since you can just write the instance and constructor directly:

```
export type XExport = { bar(): number };
export const XExport = (XReal as any) as new () => XExport
```

Which behaves even more nicely, since the IntelliSense will mention `XExport` and not `XFake`, and it looks like `XExport` just might be a "regular" class:

```
declare const c: XExport;
// const c: XExport
const ci = new XExport;
// const ci: XExport
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYiEMC8MBEBDARsNBuGAekJgB4BacmANwwBsBXAUxjAwFsmATeRAWABQASzBQmAJwBmGYCwRIA3jAAeALlYN2WCQQC+REhSpQAngAcWbTj3mDBoSLGUpeIAsTKUYUABZCIMP7ePiy0jEyCHg7QKuqYOPh2AtGwJuryLkpqMACMAEwAzDC67oZevkFBviymFkm1LABaLg0gkq6lnsZ+AVUhNPTMADQwWAywzUEY3uYRAh4NMM2o8bhJwHQYEAEAQhjiMErTqDl66+AxWOp7B6hgTADuMDcAFACUeJEklJQAfDAAPSBMBBoMBwKM5C+gUcGDAshmFjBYJS4gYwCgIAOYWY50cowwAC8XDdOkYYKj0ZjsYM5lELrAsET1K12jcYOtNtsYAANABKTHohxgkkQ72F4iYUAY4jAMAArMVioIuEwNvsWOruTy4BgANYsJRM8TvdRgTTaA66JJMZRmLGwFK8gCidodLhe-MFdBgW19YBMb19AVZvN1BsEtvt4lgix5rujsFQOv1TE+AhVas2kopDIp6njbpj6adwCELnuT0LifTgisTAgZhkLB2UrEBwUSTBUfdcYT7tQRv2po0WgkxXT3aLjrz1YHME9AqFfrhgeDrEeC6DyH+c5jXdBqvVOdLBf7xcEYPp+OAZ+nl9BpfLd03e6gk9B15iZbviaSuiAA)